# Not able to access WSO2 IS 5.3.0 admin services through angular

Tags: wso2-identity-server

We are not able to call the **ChallengeQuestionManagementAdminService** from Angular code. Getting an error stating Invalid remote address

Included the user credential in Authorization. Able to consume the service using SOAP UI but not from Angular.

Admin service : **ChallengeQuestionManagementAdminService**

Error:

```
[2019-03-26 03:33:54,314]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.authentication.AuthenticationUtil} -  Could not find IP address for domain name : 10.44.1.25:51954
[2019-03-26 03:33:54,315] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.authentication.AbstractAuthenticator} -  Invalid remote address detected.
org.wso2.carbon.core.common.AuthenticationException: Authentication Failed : Invalid remote address passed - 10.44.1.25:51954
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.services.authentication.AuthenticationUtil.validateRemoteAddress(AuthenticationUtil.java:178)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.services.authentication.AuthenticationUtil.getRemoteAddress(AuthenticationUtil.java:156)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.services.authentication.AbstractAuthenticator.getRemoteAddress(AbstractAuthenticator.java:304)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.services.authentication.AbstractAuthenticator.authenticate(AbstractAuthenticator.java:136)
        at org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.module.handler.AuthenticationHandler.isAuthenticated(AuthenticationHandler.java:180)
        at org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.module.handler.AuthenticationHandler.authenticate(AuthenticationHandler.java:105)
        at org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.module.handler.AuthenticationHandler.invoke(AuthenticationHandler.java:66)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313)
```

Answer (score 0):

[1] is the nearly corresponding code. You can check the logic. What is the version of Identity Server you are using ? If you are familiar with remote debugging, you can debug the code to find root cause [2].

[1] https://github.com/wso2/carbon-kernel/blob/4.4.x/core/org.wso2.carbon.core.services/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/core/services/authentication/AuthenticationUtil.java#L167

[2] https://medium.com/@gayanmadusanka_80721/how-to-debug-component-in-wso2-identity-server-ce15a366e9bf

Answer (score 0):

Post the request you are sending from Angular through postman and check if its successful. if yes, make sure you are sending all the required headers from Angular, else you might be missing some headers in place or your request schema might miss some params.

Headers to be included

```
    headers.set( 'Accept', '*/*'); 
    headers.set( 'Content-Type', 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8');
    headers.set( 'Authorization', `Basic ${authToken}`); <!--should send base64encode(username:password) specific to account. --> 
    headers.set( 'SOAPAction', 'urn:setUserChallengeAnswers');
```